# What does "down" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "down" mean in football (soccer) context?

75 min: Another corner for Everton, this time earned by King **down** the right. Digne sends a dangerous in-swinger into the six-yard box. Mendy flaps but just about fingertips away, then he’s clattered by Godfrey and the whistle goes for a foul.

80 min: A simple long ball **down** the right opens Everton up. Werner eases Godfrey out of the way and he’s one on one with Pickford, albeit facing a tight angle. He goes for the bottom right and Pickford kicks out for a corner.

Answer (score 2):

If a player runs "down" the pitch, they run away from their end of the pitch towards the end of the opponents.

A player can run **down** the pitch and then run back **up** again as needed.

Comment: if a player **up** the pitch, they come back. Up means come back. Am I right?

Comment: No. **UP** doesn't mean *come back*. [Why did someone upvote this comment?]