What does "down" mean in this context?
Shouldn't it be "on the left"? why does a sports writer use "down?" How does "down" work if it's correct here? Here's live commentary from the English Premier league.

Ipswich 1-1 Aston Villa (22 mins) Nice play from Ipswich down their
left as Leif Davis combines with Liam Delap whi drops deep to collect.
The former Man City academy graduate spreads play to the other wing,
but the move breaks down before it can threaten the Aston Villa goal.


See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/344780/138287 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/277326/138287 . "down their left is just saying which side of the pitch they're running on, like "running down the left [side of] the street."

@AndyBonner My confusion is why use "down" rather than "on?" It should be "on their left", right?

I think the linked questions should explain that well. Again, same as "running down the left side of the street." We could say "running down the street," and then the question is why use "down" when the street is flat, and one could just as easily use "up." After that, "the left" just specifies the person's position on the street.

You need to provide a link to the text. The sentence is spatially dependent. Here, "down" depends on the pitch, where the commentator is and where the players are, which is hard to imagine without a video. BUT 'down their left" means in the direction in which they are moving down the field towards a goal. In football (soccer) left and right depend on which direction a team is going to make a goal, which, of course, changes at half time.

down connotes extension or movement along a path or horizontal vector of some kind (when not referring to descending from a higher to a lower place). It is  movement away from an implicit vantage point. Contrast with "up":  "He walked up to her and said hello".

They walked down the street.
The decorative tile goes down the full length of the building's facade, between the first-story and second-story windows.
Look down the rifle barrel and center the little post near the muzzle between the two stanchions of the sight.
Go down the hall and make a left. It's the second room on the right.

If someone is "on my left" they are positioned on my left side. There is no sense of movement or extension entailed.
P.S.It seemed obvious to me, so I didn't say it explicitly, but I am referring to "down" with verbs of lateral motion  not vertical motion like "went down the stairs" or "climbed down the cliff".

This really seems like it's well covered in other questions to me. I had my choice of some three or four duplicates.

@AndyBonner Judging from the quick summary in the comments above I thought those answers got it wrong.  It's not just "which side".

@TimR That makes sense. So the "down" indicate smotion. Does a verb of movement need to use the preposition "down?" For instance: Every time West Ham attacked down the right, they got in behind Swansea's defence.

When coupled with a verb of motion, the preposition down has that meaning, movement (if there is actual motion involved) or extension (when the thing is stationary and the eye, human sight, moves along it).

question asks "... in this context" and you've covered everything but the context, resulting in a thoroughly misleading and incorrect answer.

This is a site about English, not football, and the football-specific answer is based on the standard use in the language (along / away), just as a recent question about the verb "break" in a horse-racing context did not need  the horse-racing rules explained to answer the question on a linguistic basis. Moreover, "down their left" does not mean the same as "downfield" even in a football context. "Down their left" refers to a corridor, as it were, not the opponent's "end" of the field.

In football (soccer), 'down' or 'downfield' means in the direction of the opposing team's goal. Conversely, 'upfield' means the opposite direction - heading towards your own goal.
This is because play is described from the perspective of the team. If a team has control of the ball and kicks it downfield, this means in the direction of the opposing team's goal. But, if the other team takes control of the ball, they want to kick it downfield, too - back towards their opponent's goal. This shouldn't be surprising - left and right are also a matter of perspective, so your example of "down their left" means the left-hand side of the pitch from the perspective of that team's direction of play.

But "Up the field" also means in the direction of the opposing team's goal. That's confusing. Which kind of preposition should we choose, up or down in the direction of a goal?

@Shakila No, that's not the case - not in association football. Upfield means in the direction of your own goal. As stated in my answer, we use down in the direction of the opponent's goal - the one a team is shooting for. But this applies to both teams. I've added some detail, hope it helps.

It is "down their left" not "downfield", and there's no need to adduce a specific sports-context meaning when one of the general meanings of the preposition suffices. For example, Cambridge glosses "down" in such a construction as "along". See down, preposition here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/down

According to this diagram, forward, front, downfield, upfield, straight, ahead, long, deep ALL mean "in the direction of the opponents' goal".

@FumbleFingers you've fundamentally misunderstood the diagram. It describes the "vertical" length of the field, which - as I stated - is dependent on the perspective of the player/team. So of course it has both terms. The term "vertical" encompasses both up and down, just as the term "horizontal" encompasses left and right.
